# Ruby file reading

Tags: ruby, file, text

I have a problem reading a file in ruby.

I am trying to read each line of a file, split it based on characters, and store that into an array. That array, which corresponds to each line, has information. I want to check if that array includes the characters "u" "d" "l" or "r" as you can see below.

IF that line doesn't include ANY of those characters, I increase a count variable by one.

The count -= 1 just takes into account a base case.

My problem is that this gives me a wrong count. For example with a text file that reads:

```
4 0 0 3 3
0 0 d 0.391538986557049
0 1 ur 63.1258159853081 3.14882640637611
0 2 rd 0.0148854629087619 0.019301544005463
0 3 u 15.6415340291405
```

count is supposed to be 0.

```
def compute_closed(file)
    count = 0
    while line = file.gets do
        array = line.split(//)  
        answer = array.include?("u" || "d" || "l" || "r")
        if answer != true 
            count += 1
        end
    end
    count -= 1
    puts count
end
```

Comment: Dear `array.include?("u" || "d" || "l" || "r")` not valid. it takes only one argument.

Comment: oh ok thanks. Can you let me know of an equivalent?

Comment: You give us actual text file content,and expected output

Comment: Give @ArupRakshit the actual text file and 10 seconds (max) :-)

Comment: TEXT:4 0 0 3 3
0 0 d 0.391538986557049
0 1 ur 63.1258159853081 3.14882640637611
0 2 rd 0.0148854629087619 0.019301544005463
0 3 u 15.6415340291405
1 0 dr 0.889878639213553 16.597130417636
1 1 dulr 25.6907194043197 0.577082416767899 11.2788559044107 0.0116108917113176
1 2 url 9.93466159987408 1.26393492879008 0.199913563972552
1 3

Comment: Count should be 1 since there is one line that doesn't have at least one occurrence (aside from the first line) of any of the four letters

Comment: what is `u`,`ur`,`dr` ?

Comment: Part of a maze, u = up, d = down, etc

Comment: We can't know your text file's lines like this. Please edit your post and code format the text file.

Comment: Nvm I figured it out. thanks tho.

Comment: Instead of include, you could just use intersect `&` for instance: expected = ["a", "b", "c"], then just do `array & expected` That will give you the intersection between the 2 sets. If there's something in it, means it did have any of those letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have a reason for splitting the line up into bits, but if you're just checking for those characters somewhere in the line, why not use a regex?

```
def compute_closed(file)
    count = 0
    while line = file.gets do
        count += 1 if line =~ /[udlr]/
    end
    count -= 1
    puts count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need to split the lines up by character, then you may want to use sets instead of arrays:

```
def compute_closed(file)
  count = 0

  while line = file.gets do
    cmp_set = Set.new ['u', 'd', 'l', 'r']
    input_set = Set.new(line.split(//))

    if input_set.intersection(cmp_set).size == 0
        count += 1
    end
  end

  count -= 1
  puts count
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: after posting I see my answer is essentially the same as @Philip's, but I'll leave it up for the slightly different treatment.

There are many ways to do this.  Here's another:

```
File.read('f1').each_line.reduce(0) {|t,s| t + (s =~ /[udlr]/ ? 0 : 1)} - 1
```

Let's try it:

```
text =<<_
Now is the time
for all good
Rubiests to
spend some
time in Hawaii. 
_

File.write('f1', text)
File.read('f1').each_line.reduce(0) {|t,s| t+(s =~ /[udlr]/ ? 0 : 1)} - 1 #=> 1
```

It returns `2 - 1 => 1` because if finds a 'u,' 'd', 'l' or 'r' in all but the the first and last rows.

Initially, I had

```
 File.read(fname).each_line.each_with_object(0) {|s,t|
   t += 1 unless s =~ /[udlr]/ } - 1
```

but `t` would not increment.  I was puzzled, so emailed my friend @ArupRakshit, who I can always count on to know the answer, or dig until he finds it.  It [turns out that](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/each_with_object) in

```
...each_with_object(memo) {|s,memo|
```

`memo` must be a mutable object, an important difference between that method and `reduce/inject` (which is *not* made clear in the Ruby docs for [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)).  Thanks, Arup.